# Some dumb questions about Cocoa C-style functions

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

In spite of I'm developing for years in Cocoa, I never have to develop a kind of C-style library for working on non-objects vars.

What I call "C-style functions" is, for example:

```
float myCStyleFunction(float var1, float var2);
```

Knowing Objective-C is a descendant of C, I was trying to make a real C function. But some simple things are not permitted by the compilator.

First the pass-by-reference :

```
void makeSomethingWithImages(CGImageRef & im1, CGImageRef & im1);
```

This do not work. Compilator says `Parameter name omitted`. **Is there a way to pass-by-reference my CGImages?**

Secondly, defaults parameters :

```
void makeSomethingWithImages(CGImageRef im1, CGImageRef im1, float tolerance) { ... }

void makeSomethingWithImages(CGImageRef im1, CGImageRef im1) {
    makeSomethingWithImages(im1, im2, 0);
}
```

Error : `Conflicting types for 'makeSomethingWithImages'`

**Is there a way to have some defaults parameters?**

And the subsidiary question : if Obj-C is a C descendant, why these examples do not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass by reference is C++ not c so is default parameters and function overloading, though clang adds extensions to c for function overloading but there is addition syntax for that.

Comment: With `void makeSomethingWithImages(CGImageRef im1, CGImageRef im1)`, are the parameters copied when the function is called?

Comment: @Martin Yes. The only way to avoid that is to send pointers instead. References would be nice, but Objective-C doesn't support it. Incidentally, `CGImageRefs` are already pointers, so the copying is minimal as it is.

Comment: Oh, yes, they are pointers you're right. Do you have an explanation about my second question (different functions signatures that conflicts), or is it the same: only available in C++?

Comment: different function signatures, function overloading, is c++ only also, but clang has c extensions to support that requires a little bit more syntax, see the following link http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#function-overloading-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the link. My C & C++ knowledge is a bit far, I was sure that was some C features.

Answer (score 0):

Pass by reference shall be using the-`*` notation(**pointer to the Address**), `&` is a "**Value at Address**", `CGImageRef` is defined as `CGImage *CGImageRef;` in `CGImage.h` class  so the compiler Err..

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use by-reference passing mechanism, nor default value for arguments in C. If Obj-C is a descendant of C, this means that legal C code is accepted by Obj-C compilation, not the converse.

But you've made a mistake, by-reference and default values are not available in Objective-C. Both of these constructions are C++ ones, not C ones. There exists a mix of Objective-C and C++, it is called Objective-C++.

Both C++ and Objective-C are descendant of C, so the mix.